# How to engrave music note by note in a measure in lilypond

Tags: lilypond, engraving

A measure is shown here:

[image: RH = whole-note octave; LH = four AC-F eighth note pairs]

How to notate this is in lilypond on a note by note basis on a grand staff.

The note F5 in the treble clef is given as two lists, one for notes and other for duration

`F5 -> [rest,'F4',rest],timing = [0,4,0],` 4 denotes four quarter notes

Likewise

F6 -> [rest,'F4',rest],timing = [0,4,0]

A3 -> [rest,'A3',rest],timing = [0,0.5,3.5]

C4 -> [rest,'C4',rest],timing = [0,0.5,3.5]

F3 -> [rest,'F3',rest],timing = [0.5,0.5,3]

A3 -> [rest,'A3',rest],timing = [1,0.5,2.5]

C4 -> [rest,'C4',rest],timing = [1,0.5,2.5]

F3 -> [rest,'F3',rest],timing = [0.5,0.5,3]

A3 -> [rest,'A3',rest],timing = [2,0.5,1.5]

C4 -> [rest,'C4',rest],timing = [2,0.5,1.5]

F3 -> [rest,'F3',rest],timing = [2.5,0.5,1]

A3 -> [rest,'A3',rest],timing = [3,0.5,0.5]

C4 -> [rest,'C4',rest],timing = [3,0.5,0.5]

F3 -> [rest,'F3',rest],timing = [3.5,0.5,0]

How to convert the above notes and durations in lilypond to generate a music engraving?
Basically is there a possibility in lilypond to generate a note by note syntax for the whole measure?

Comment: You never explained where the information that looks like `F5 -> [rest,'F4',rest],timing = [0,4,0]` is coming from.  Basically, you shouldn't follow any of that, except maybe the note names.  Have you looked at the [Learning Manual](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/learning/index.html)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will generate the measure shown in the question:

```
\new GrandStaff
<<
    \new Staff \relative { <f'' f'>1 }
    \new Staff \relative { \clef bass <a c>8 f8 <a c>8 f8 <a c>8 f8 <a c>8 f8 }
>>
```